# How to deletingFirstPathComponent for URL?

Tags: swift

Is there a clean way to delete the beginning path components of a file path? The beginning of the file path usually has sensitive directory names like the username: `file:///Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Device/F2CD5625-EE71/etc/Application/data.dat`

I'd like to redact the beginning path and end up with something like: `***/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Device/F2CD5625-EE71/etc/Application/data.dat`

When I start implementing it starts to get really messy and hoping there's something close to native in this. This is what I'm starting with:

```
extension URL {

    func deletingFirstPathComponent(_ items: Int = 1) -> URL {
        pathComponents.dropFirst(items) // construct back to URL?
    }
}
```

Is there something in Swift to help more with this or a better approach? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this only for logging purposes? Because dropping or replacing path components and convert them back to (invalid) URLs doesn't seem to be particularly useful.

Comment: Yes exactly for logging purposes

Comment: I updated the question to make it a little more useful, to truncate the beginning instead of reconstructing as an invalid URL

Comment: If you can ensure that file paths are in the current home directory you could try to print by [abbreviatingWithTildeInPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407943-abbreviatingwithtildeinpath). Another option might be [os_log](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/migrating-to-unified-logging-swift-edition/) (not sure if suits your case though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a string for logging you can use a regular expression to select and replace the user info

```
let hidden = url.path.replacingOccurrences(of: #"/Users/\w*/"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

This gives *Library/...* but you can of course replace with /***/ or something else

Or work with some array functionality

```
let removed = url.path.split(separator: "/")[2...].joined(separator: "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Late for the party, but I ran into a similar situation, and I came up with this solution that preserves schema and others.

```
extension URL {
    var deletingFistPathComponent: URL? {
        if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
            assert((urlComponents.path as NSString).pathComponents.first == "/")
            urlComponents.path = "/" + ((urlComponents.path as NSString).pathComponents.dropFirst(2)).joined(separator: "/")
            return urlComponents.url
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```